# How do I notify our targets that a petition has been signed?

Tags: civicampaign

I am creating a petition with multiple targets. Is it possible to have them be notified via email each time the petition is signed? Or is it possible to CC them in the email confirmation the petition signer receives?

Comment: I can't comment on Civi - but if you are using Drupal with civicrm there may be some nicer solutions via Webform_civicrm module

Answer (score 2):

The extension "[Petition Email](https://civicrm.org/extensions/petition-email)" should let you do this in CiviCRM.